# Loop a matrix and a vector

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have a vector with 2 elements `a_destinations` that represent the source and destination with two integers. `2 4` or `5 1`...

I have a matrix `test` as follows:

```
0 15 15 15 13 13 15 15 13 13 15 15 15 13 15 15 
2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 10 2 2 2 10 2 
6 1 2 3 3 3 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 2 2 3 4 4 2 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 3 3 3 4 5 3 3 8 8 3 3 3 8 3 3 
9 4 4 4 4 5 4 4 4 9 4 4 4 9 4 4 
7 2 2 2 2 2 6 7 7 7 11 11 7 7 11 7 
12 6 6 3 3 3 6 7 8 8 12 12 12 12 12 12 
9 7 7 7 4 4 7 7 8 9 7 7 7 9 7 7 
13 8 8 8 8 5 8 8 8 9 13 13 13 13 13 13 
14 1 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 10 11 11 11 14 14 
12 6 6 12 12 12 6 12 12 12 10 11 12 12 10 12 
15 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 13 11 11 12 13 11 15 
0 12 12 12 9 9 12 12 9 9 12 12 12 13 12 12 
15 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 14 15 
0 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 14 12 12 12 14 15
```

where `test[i][j]` represents the path `from i to j`

each time `test[i][j] != j` we do the loop again

Example:

path from 2 to 4 >> `test[2][4] = 3`, `test[3][4] = 4`: we output: 2, 3, 4

path from 1 to 7 >> `test[1][7] = 2`, `test[2][7] = 6` , `test[6][7] = 7`: we output 1, 2 ,6, 7

I tried as follows:

```
std::vector<vector<int>> test;
test = Graphe->P; // MATRIX IS FILLED like on top
vector< int > a_destinations; // Vector with the destinations: 2 4 or 5 10 or 1 4 ...

for ( unsigned i = 0; i < test.size(); i++){
    for (unsigned j = 0; j< test.size(); j++){
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < a_destinations->size() - 1 ; k ++){
             if ( a_destinations->at(k) == i && a_destinations->at(k+1) == j ){
                   if (test[i][j] == a_destinations->at(k+1)){
                        cout << a_destinations->at(k) << ", " <<test[i][j];
                   } else {
                        cout << a_destinations->at(k) << ", " << test[a_destinations->at(k)][j];
                   }
                        cout << ", " << test[i][j];// << ", " << a_destinations->at(k+1);

                        }
                }      
        }
}
```

But i end up with 2 destinations always.

Comment: Unless you populate `a_destinations` this code is kind of pointless. `size()` will always be 0.

Comment: The test size is 15, its filled already

Comment: Not in this code it isn't. If you expect us to follow along, don't over-simplify your code.